# Why all code runs in parallel and not in sequence?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have the following code:

```
   let x = new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {setTimeout(function(){console.log('Timeout');resolve(1);},10000);console.log('Something');})
   let y = x.then (new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {setTimeout(function(){console.log('Timeout');resolve(1);},10000);console.log('Something');}))
   let z = y.then (new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {setTimeout(function(){console.log('Timeout');resolve(1);},10000);console.log('Something');}))

  console.log(x,y,z);
```

I **"forgot"** to put a return statement in the assignment of *let y* and *let x*
The output was (i'm ignoring last line of code):
First it prints "Something" 3 times
then waited for 10 second and then printed "Timeout" 3 times.

What i think that should be is:
then after 10 sec printing "Timeout" only once.
Now after first *Promise* is resolved I'm expecting (since I **"forgot** to return the two next promises), is to print "Something" for the the let y assignment and then immediately print print "Something" again for the z assignment.
Then the code should wait 10 seconds and immediately print Timeout twice.
The big question is why Something is printed immediately X3 and not only once and then after 10 second should be printed twice

Comment: The `then` method expects a function as argument! Not a Promise instance.

Comment: a `Promise` executor is evaluated immediately (synchronously). Wrap `then` expression into a function.

Comment: @trincot,  so what happens in my case (when i didn't send a function)

Comment: What happens is that all three promises are created synchronously. By consequence all three `setTimeout` calls happen immediately as well, which means they expire at the same time, 10 seconds later. The fact that you have  two `then` calls really doesn't add anything to that. They are quite irrelevant to the main working of your code.

Comment: if an argument passed to `then` is not a function, it is ignored (`then` doesn't do anything with it).

Comment: Don't use `let` if you don't need to reassign later. Also, please format your code.

Comment: @mzedeler this is the way i write.. Don't know to format it better

Comment: @marzelin. you said: `then doesn't do anything with it` , but actually it does prints Something and Timeout. So what did you mean when you said this?

Comment: @Eitanos30 it's not because `then` is doing something, it's because `new Promise(executor)` is an expression that itself causes things to happen. If you move that expression outside of `then()`, you'll get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you don't pass a function to the `then` calls. Your code evaluates the argument passed to the `then` method immediately (synchronously) and so your code creates the three promises immediately. So you get three prints of "Something" as the three `setTimeout` calls are also made immediately. It is no surprise that these three timers expire together 10 seconds later, and so you get again three prints in the console.

When you pass *functions* as arguments to `then`, you'll have the guarantee that those functions will be called only when the promise (on which `then` is called) is resolved.

Unrelated, but as the code for the three promises is the same, I would create a function for it. This will also make very clear how you should pass *that* function to the `then` method, *without* calling it yourself.

Another issue in your code is that the final console log, will print three promise objects, while it seems more logical to print the three resolved values (1, 1, 1). For that you can use `Promise.all`.

I will use a time out of 2 seconds here, so you can quickly see the output:

```js
function printAfter2() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('Timeout expired');
            resolve(1);
        }, 2000);
        console.log('Executed setTimeout');
    });
}

let x = printAfter2();
let y = x.then(printAfter2); // Note that we do not execute printAfter2.
let z = y.then(printAfter2);

Promise.all([x,y,z]).then(console.log);
```

Comment: thanks! can you please explain how `.then(console.log);` prints something you didn't send nothing to log function

Comment: That's because it is not us that make the call, it is the Promise internals that register this function as the callback to call when the promise resolves. So *it* will make the call at the time of resolution, passing it the value it resolves with. It is equivalent to `.then(value => console.log(value))`, but that just makes a useless wrapper arrow function... we might as well pass the function itself and not the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks.. i understand... The result of `
Promise.all([x,y,z])` is the resolve value of each `Promise`?

Comment: Yes, as an array.